# SignalR (ASP .Net) - "The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format" - problem with websocket using own Java Websocket Client

Tags: java, websocket, signalr, signalr.client

I'm working on websocket integration to Bittrex - v3 API (https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#topic-Authenticating). Bittrex websocket implementation is  based on Microsoft ASP.net’s SignalR - they are not using ASP.net Core’s SignalR implementation.

I'm working on my own Java Client (based on Vert.x) because there is no available actual java client to SignalR.

I've encountered an problem.  I want to connect with Bittrex websocket using my own websocket client developed in Java but I’m receiving 400 with information that “The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format”.  I don’t know the SignalR protocol, I’ve only made some chrome debugging of bittrex website to get knowledge how can I connect using websocket.

How the process of the connection looks like in my case:

Step 1. I’m requesting for a connection token usign this GET request:

encoded: [https://socket-v3.bittrex.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=[{%22name%22:%22c3%22}]&_=1600500715881](https://socket-v3.bittrex.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22:%22c3%22%7D%5D&_=1600500715881)

decoded: [https://socket-v3.bittrex.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=[{"name":"c3"}]&_=1600500715881](https://socket-v3.bittrex.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22:%22c3%22%7D%5D&_=1600500715881)

Step: 2. Nest using the response like:

{"Url":"/signalr","ConnectionToken":"0kBiAOYeOtyGleCNodFQjl6TxKgBZy6o8RmI96GxteRH+GPfeycU+cyODS8YiAgpvCJ4RTmuQYh3Gr6TKo7U1K/nwi1CQxuaBroX0iF6j/wKxkeU","ConnectionId":"c79d4fa4-7518-4dc3-8884-0885598b105d","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"ProtocolVersion":"2.0","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}

I’m creating a request to establish WS connection using:

host: socket-v3.bittrex.com

port: 443

requestUri (encoded): /signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.0&connectionToken=0kBiAOYeOtyGleCNodFQjl6TxKgBZy6o8RmI96GxteRH+GPfeycU+cyODS8YiAgpvCJ4RTmuQYh3Gr6TKo7U1K/nwi1CQxuaBroX0iF6j/wKxkeU&connectionData%3D%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22c3%22%7D%5D&tid=0

requestUri (decoded): /signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.0&connectionToken=0kBiAOYeOtyGleCNodFQjl6TxKgBZy6o8RmI96GxteRH GPfeycU cyODS8YiAgpvCJ4RTmuQYh3Gr6TKo7U1K/nwi1CQxuaBroX0iF6j/wKxkeU&connectionData=[{"name":"c3"}]&tid=0

(tid is always constant in the request)

Maybe someone also have the same problem. Do you have any idea what could be wrong? I was trying to put also a ConnectionId into the requestUri but it also did not help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try use Percent-encoding(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for connectionToken and connectionData